# How to create a DB Link to a Database which has failover in TNS

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, database-link

Could you please help me to understand how my DB LINK creation sql look like to a database (RAC env, Oracle 12c) which have fail over  option in tns entry?

I read below post from Oracle-(not having access to view below url since I do not have Oracle Support membership)

> Don't create a DBLink using a TNS connect string configured for failover. #Database links don't support TAF or Failover. See the following: Database Link: DBLink Creation using TAF or SCAN TNS Connect String (Doc ID 399453.1)
>   https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/399453_1.html

Does it means that we have to remove fail-over, connect etc options from tns entry and then create db link? 
My TNS entry is below(just a sample)

```
panda.host.com=
(DESCRIPTION =(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=10)(RETRY_DELAY=1)
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = panda.host.com )(PORT = 1521)) 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = panda-sb.host.com )(PORT = 1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = panda_app.host.com ))))
```

I am now trying to create a DB link in another database pointing to this database so based on above fact **which of below sql is correct and will be working?** In 'using' clause I am providing connection descriptor since I am not allowed to make changes in tnsnames.ora.

```
1. 

   CREATE DATABASE LINK TEST_LINK connect to REMOTE_SCHEMA identified by "MyPass" using
'(DESCRIPTION =(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
    (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=10)(RETRY_DELAY=1)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = panda.host.com )(PORT = 1521)) 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = panda-sb.host.com )(PORT = 1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = panda_app.host.com ))))';



2. 

CREATE DATABASE LINK TEST_LINK connect to REMOTE_SCHEMA identified by "MyPass" using
'(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = panda.host.com )(PORT = 1521)) 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP )(HOST = panda-sb.host.com )(PORT = 1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = panda_app.host.com ))))';

//failover and connect options are removed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced MOS just states the following:

- Dblinks do not support TAF. This refers to `FAILOVER_MODE` parameter, not `FAILOVER`. The first parameter is about TAF, the second is about connect-time failover.
- It is not recommended to use the SCAN address for dblinks in case of RAC. Instead of the SCAN address, use the VIP addresses.

Removing `FAILOVER` parameter will not change anything, the default parameter for it is `ON`.

[FAILOVER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-4A20F0A2-EDCD-4006-9177-2EA4B12D656D)

You do not need to remove connect-time failover parameters.

Comment: While connecting from application server (like Weblogic, using jdbc thin driver, ojdbc6.jar) which should be most approprite url? I did simple jdbc connectivity test, and found that below 3 are working, but need to understand which one is most preferrable and must be used - 
**1.** `my.jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@<1st_connect_string>` 
<b>
**2.** `my.jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@<2nd_connect_string> `
<b>
**3.** `my.jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/service_name> `